# Why chrome not able to authenticate proxy even after supplying password

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, authentication, internet-explorer-9

I am facing this rather weird issue: with proxy.
In my organisation we are using proxy.
What I am able to do:

- I am able to connect to internet using **IE 9**.
- I am able to connect to internet using chrome(34.0.1847.131 m) as well but there is the issue

Chrome ask for proxy authentication and I supply the same, infact saved them(with my domain/user and password, I have tried without domain as well). But I believe supplying those details to chrome doesn't matter atall as when that authentication window appears it never goes, irrespective of supplying the user and password and at times no authentication windows but I can access the net.

What is working then:

If I refresh the proxy session in IE i.e. opening new tab and visiting some website, and then I try connected some site through chrome it gets connected, never ask for any proxy authentication.

Now seeing this I guess chrome from its side not able to provide proxy authentication, and somehow its using IE sessions only.

**How can I make it work,** because I don't want to open IE every time to use chrome, and worst thing is chrome ask for authentication every 5 min, if i do not refresh in IE I just cannot use chrome.

Sorry for the long text. I tied to summarize it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to tell us what authentication mechanism is in use, and which proxy server is being used.

I suggest you install Fiddler, which will provide you valuable insight into what is happening with http (and https) connections from your Windows client.

Also, you need to look at the proxy server logs.